# Meaning of "within the day"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

My broker sent me this email:

> This is an automated message to alert you that your overall account
>   value has just decreased by -10% within the day.

The broker claims that this message means, the account decreased by 10% **from the beginning** and is more or less ignoring the `within the day`.
I am Austrian and therefore not an English native speaker but an English friend [from Liverpool] read the email and she told me that the email means the account value decreased by these 10% **in 1 day** - be more specific: The previous day the email was sent.

**My question:**
How is this email really to be understood? Is it clear what the broker says that they mean the account value decreased by 10% from the beginning, or
does it mean the account value decreased by 10% that one day?

**Another point:**
When writing *decrease* I consider the minus sign in the percentage value also as not correct. The word *decrease* is precise enough so in my eyes it should be like this: `..has just decreased by 10%...`

I am asking because this a one of the biggest brokers and they send in my eyes not clear statements.

So, in the end I would have expected the email something like this:

`... has just decreased by 10% since the account was opened.`

Comment: If this is indeed the decrease "from the beginning", then I guess that "within the day" tells you that your account passed that 10% mark during the previous 24 hours.  But I agree that my first guess would be as your Liverpudlian friend said.

Comment: I agree with your point about the _-10%_ -- that looks redundant and illogical.

Comment: To decrease by -10% means to increase by 10%. I believe the use of the minus sign here was a mistake.

Comment: I would argue that the meaning of the message is that you need a new broker.  (If they're not going to be careful about messages to their clients, will they be careful in managing your account?)  

Normally, I would expect _within the day_ to be used in a future context, as in "_I will respond within the day_."  In this instance, when combined with "has just", I would take it to mean that your value is 90% of what it was yesterday -- the decrease has occurred in the last 24 hours.  If they wanted to say that it just _passed_ the 90% mark, they ought to say it just _reached_ or _passed_ it.

Comment: Also, the minus sign was almost certainly an error -- which leads me to wonder if your account has fallen in value because they purchased or sold negative amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Within the day" seems pretty meaningless in this context. The phrase is commonly used to refer to the future ("we will deliver it within the/a day," or some number of days) or a 24 hour period. Here is an example: [‘Handmaid’s Tale’ Wines Pulled Within A Day Of Backlash](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/handmaids-tale-themed-wines-pulled-within-a-day-after-backlash_us_5b460af7e4b048036ea4baa1), meaning it was pulled within 24 hours.

So, for your example, I would expect something more specific like: "since the start of trading today", or "in the past 24 hours" or, if it really does mean what they claim, "since the account was opened" (as you suggest).

I think this is an example of the problems caused by letting engineers or non-English speakers write automated messages!

Comment: Or letting money men write them.  (My dad was a CPA but my mom wrote all the correspondence so the grammar and spelling was impeccable.)